# How to Display multiple values stored in database one column with delimiter?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having multiple values in database column. How to display them as table?
Here $ working as delimiter.

```
machine_description = "CHUCK#8"$JOB DIAMETER#250 MM$JOB LENGTH#450 MM$ CONTROL#FANUC OTC"
```

I want to display this as table:

```
______________________
|CHUCK   |  8"       |
______________________
|DIAMETER|  250 MM   |
_____________________
|LENGTH  |  450 MM   |
______________________
|CONTROL |  FANUC OTC|
```

pasting values like this because stack doesn't allow me put image here right now.

Comment: hey lovely guys out there, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need HTML table, then you can use something like this:

```
<?php
$machine_description = 'CHUCK#8"$JOB DIAMETER#250 MM$JOB LENGTH#450 MM$ CONTROL#FANUC OTC';
$data = explode('$', $machine_description);
echo '<table>';
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    echo '<tr><td>' . str_replace('#', '</td><td>', $row) . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

That will give you table like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>CHUCK</td>
    <td>8"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>JOB DIAMETER</td>
    <td>250 MM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>JOB LENGTH</td>
    <td>450 MM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> CONTROL</td>
    <td>FANUC OTC</td>
</tr>
</table>
```